# What is the Aggregation, Delegation and Association in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, oop

In an interview, interviewer asked this this question. I know association, we achieve associations using [Mappings](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations).Please help to understand Aggregation and Delegation in hibernate.

Comment: I consider this question as a very interesting one. _Aggregation_ and _Composition_ are very confusing terms, especially in Java (compared to C++). Hibernate adds more meaning to an ownership part of these terms.  Also, probably, _Composition_ should be used in place of _Delegation_ in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate supports multiple aggregate functions. Aggregate functions are used in HQL queries, they return an aggregate value like avg(), sum(), count(*) etc calculated from property values of all objects satisfying other query criteria.

The mapping of associations between entity classes and the relationships between tables is the soul of ORM. Following are the four ways in which the cardinality of the relationship between the objects can be expressed. An association mapping can be unidirectional as well as bidirectional.

1. Many-to-One
2. One-to-One
3. One-to-Many
4. Many-to-Many

Answer (score 0):

*Aggregation* in SQL usually refers to (Aggregation) Functions like `count()`, `sum()` or `avg()`, and the HQL offers a subset of those functions. [Read about it in the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/queryhql-aggregation.html).

*Aggregation* in Hibernate (or the mentioned "Composition") refers to the concept of Embeddable Types, [read all about it here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/embeddables.html). Instead of providing a dedicated Table for aggregates, you can embed it into the parent type.